# In the /etc/nsswitch.conf file what is db and how do I edit the db?

Tags: networking, nsswitch

My nsswitch file contains the following

```
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

What is the meaning of the db value? For example in the protocols section I see db I assume this means so sort of database but where is this db? and is it just a plain text config file. If it is just a config file why wouldn't it just be files? And if it is a DB how do I edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db` causes `libnss_db` to be used. That reads data from Berkeley DB files usually stored in `/var/db` ([`/var/lib/misc` on Debian](https://sources.debian.org/src/libnss-db/2.2.3pre1-6/debian/conf/default/)); this is typically faster than reading from plain text files, for large NSS databases.

You should be able to modify the databases with a Berkeley DB client, but they’re typically built wholesale from the relevant source data. In the configuration above, the data sources are text files in `/etc`, and these remain the reference; the DB file is a variant used for speed, built wholesale using `makedb`, and not intended as the primary storage. The text files here are `/etc/protocols` for protocols, `/etc/services` for services, `/etc/ethers` for Ethernet addresses, `/etc/rpc` for RPC program numbers.

It’s more common to see `db` used for the `passwd` and `group` databases, as a local cache for large, remotely-hosted user databases (typically using LDAP).